# Errors including the custom model method in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

## What I tried to do

I tried to make custom admin method to include product thumbnail preview in my admin panel. `product_thumbnail` is a `ImageField` inside the `Product` Model which has general information of each products that I upload on the admin panel.

I wanted to make `product_thumbnail` as **not required**. Therefore, I set `null=True` and `blank=True` in my models.py also.

```py
class Product(TimeStampModel):

    ...
    product_thumbnail = models.ImageField(verbose_name='상품사진', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='product_thumbnail')
```

I created the custom function as below and included it in `list_display` admin option inside of `ProductAdmin` model.

```py
def thumbnail_preview(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.product_thumbnail.url}" width="40%" />')
thumbnail_preview.short_description = '상품사진'
```

## Which error did I get?

I got the error as below:

```sh
ValueError: The 'product_thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

## What I have tried to solve issue

This might be because some `Product` may not have `product_thumbnail` so that Django admin failed to load its url due to its null value.

1. I used try-except so that if Django fails to find `product_thumbnail` associated with that product, then it can throw error text.

```py
def thumbnail_preview(self, obj):
        try: 
            return mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.product_thumbnail.url}" width="40%" />')
        except obj.product_thumbnail is None:
            return HttpResponse('No images')
thumbnail_preview.short_description = '상품사진'
```

Then I got another error as below:

```sh
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

I already applied migrations. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `except obj.product_thumbnail is None:`, but this is very incorrect! After the `except` keyword you are supposed to specify an *exception class*, not write some condition. Better yet why even use exceptions here? Generally one should avoid exceptions when one can do so, considering that if a `FileField` / `ImageField` has no file then they are considered falsy you can write the below code to solve your problem:

```
def thumbnail_preview(self, obj):
    if obj.product_thumbnail:
        return  mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.product_thumbnail.url}" width="40%" />')
    return HttpResponse('No images')
thumbnail_preview.short_description = '상품사진'
```

Comment: Your answer did help a lot. I think I should distinguish when to use try-except and when to use if clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means that file is not uploaded in field at all, but you are trying to get its URL which is impossible of course, just wrap in condition. See another way to fix with using templates:

https://fixexception.com/django/the-s-attribute-has-no-file-associated-with-it/

Comment: I found another nice solution down below, but anyway I will also take your comment as a great resource!